# AJAX jQUERY beginner. Get Request for pagination without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I am implementing pagination.

```
GET     /profile/:id           controllers.Application.profile(id : Int)
```

I have a list of items and display only 5 of them per page. 
For e.g for route

```
localhost:9000/profile/1
```

I load the first 5 items and so on. The problem is that I have 4 sections on the page with pagination, so I need to go to the next page without reloading the page, to keep other sections at the page they are at the moment. How to do this? I am new to Ajax and jQuery. I pass to this view the number of items and the items.

```
 @for(event <- eventsCreated) {
                <div class="my-event">


                    @if(event.eventPhoto != ""){
                        <img src="@{"/image"}?image=@event.eventPhoto" height=200 width=300 class="img-responsive my-event-photo">
                    }else{
                        <img src="@routes.Assets.at("assets/icons/Forma-3.png")" class="img-responsive my-event-photo">
                    }

                    <div class="my-event-details">
                        <p><a href='@{"/events/details/"}@event.eventId'>@event.eventName</a></p>
                        <p>@event.eventDescription</p>
                        <i class="flaticon-location"></i><i class="flaticon-thumbs1"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }


        <!-- bootstrap pagination -->
        <nav aria-label="Page">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>



   <!-- here I tried to do this by myself but it does nothing -->

             <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="" onclick="Profile()">2</a></li>

   <!-- ============================================= -->

                    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                    <li class="page-item">
                        <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </nav>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Profile($scope, $http) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/profile/2',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(d){
            alert(d.status);
        }
    });
}
```

If this information is important, I am using play2 framework